# What is the best dp dimensions to make your xml layouts as a base for?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-emulator

What Dp and emulator is the best for developing xml layouts on android with eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Best" is subjective. I'd advise just starting with a common resolution like 800x480 and hdpi (which is a common density now), but you'll want to test with a variety of resolutions and densities, and in fact for a complicated application you might end up developing layouts for multiple screen sizes/densities at which time you'll have to create appropriately different emulators or find appropriate devices to develop and test on.

Comment: Do they all convert fine? Or does only 160 by 160( base)  convert?

Comment: They should all scale appropriately, but for best image quality you should provide a separate set of assets for each targeted density. Definitely read the doc on [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) that MisterSquonk mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Read [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

There is no 'best' - you should either target specific devices / screen-sizes / resolutions or be prepared to develop generically and compensate with different images / layouts etc.